# URL rewriting - some rule works and some other doesn't

Tags: apache, apache2, url-rewriting, httprequest

My Apache2.2 seems to work like this: when I request `www.site.com/name` first it is looking for folder `/name/`, if not found, next it is searching for file `name.php`.

But when I turn on `RewriteEngine On` in .htaccess and add `RewriteRule ^name$ name2.php`, then Apache still will be looking if there is folder or file `name` in spite of RewriteRule.

How can I give RewriteRule priority?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html - "Negotiation in Apache" section, "Multiviews" subtitle:

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.* (...)

So in my case (I use mod_userdir), I edited `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
  (...)
  <Directory /home/*public_html>
    (...)
    #Options MultiViewes # I COMMENTED OUT THIS OPTION
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Now if I request `www.domain.com/foo` apache **won't** search for file named `foo` in directory! And from now on `RewriteRule ^name$ another-name.php` **will work**.